# error message and [Process completed] as soon as I open the terminal MAC OS Monterrey 12.5.1

Tags: macos, terminal

After restarting my computer, I got an error message on the console, I don't know what might have caused it, but I can't use the terminal at all now. Whenever I start it, I get an error and a [Process completed]  message
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some rust (cargo) binary looks like it's been added to your shell startup script and is causing it to fail on startup.

I would try navigating to your $HOME folder (using Finder) and then turn on Hidden files (Cmd+Shift+`.`)

Look for `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` and try moving them temporarily to your Desktop. Then try running Terminal again. If it works, just examine the profile/rc file and look for the troublesome bit to remove.

Comment: Hi there, I just tried that, but I am still facing the same issue

Comment: @EduardoSerrano Rename your `~/.cargo` folder to `.cargo.bak`